# Transfer files to linux from UNC path in PHP

Tags: php, samba, smb

I have a script that transfers files from one directory to another. I have a Ubuntu VM, and before I just used the UNC path with `scandir()` in PHP and then used `copy()` to transfer them and that worked fine. Now that I'm on Ubuntu, it says none of the files can be found when I know they are there. Is there something like smb-get for PHP that would enable me to do this?

Comment: Can you write an example path that "isn't there"? Try wrapping the directory path in `dirname()`

Comment: You may want to review that you have the correct slashes, Windows uses backslash while Unix/Linux uses forward slash.